# Not able to find database in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

A couple of versions ago, I was able to pull the app database from `/data/data/com.pkg.addr/databases` directory. But now, I'm not even able to see the `databases` directory. There have been many changes in code, so before venturing into rolling back to see what went wrong, I want to check if anyone has any pointers into the possible reasons why I can't get to the db.

Or has anything changed in the last few sdk updates?

Thanks,
Rajath

Comment: pls make one thing clear to me are you using the emulator or the Phone

Comment: No changes are made in the latest SDK that hides the database folder.It shows empty when the database file has been deleted.Are you able to access it from the application?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to access the database from the application.

Comment: I'm using the emulator, as the question heading states.

Comment: OK, are you able to see your package in the data/data folder?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to see the package folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone, I was creating the database with `null` being passed as the name of the db.